# Android: how to open new intent from ListView, hosted in TabHost, inside same FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost, listactivity

I looked through tons of articles how to open new Activity from ListView hosted by TabHost.
I have a TabHost Activity, one of the tabs has ListView, with clickable list items.
On item click, I want new Activity to be opened in the same FrameLayout.
My code for calling new Activity looks as following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), displayRSS.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

This opens just new Activity.
I want new Activity to be opened instead of current ListActivity.

Would appreciate any possible solutions on this.

Comment: do you want open new activity in same tab or something else

Comment: @Maneesh, I want to do it in the same tab

Answer (score 0):

If u want to open the activity in the same tab, do the following

while creating tabs, u have to launch activity group in that tab as

```
Tabspec tabspec=getTabHost().newTabSpec("title").setContent(new Intent(TabGroupActivityEx.class,"unique string"));
getTabHost().addTab(tabspec);
```

under this tab group activity launch an activity that contains list view, when an item click launch another activity with `setContentView()` then u will get as u required.

Comment: I have the following code: <br />// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
     intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ruActivity.class);

     // Initialize Главная tab
     spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("main").setIndicator("Главная",
                       res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                   .setContent(intent);
     tabHost.addTab(spec); <br /> and where should I setContentView() specify?